# What is the easiest way to send angular array to codeigniter controller

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, post

What is the easiest whay to send js array from angular controler to my Codeigniter controler.I want this to print this
     `Array ( [kalorije] => 0 [proteini] => 0 [uh] => 0 [masti] => 0 )`.
Please test it before ansering and tell me if i need to set up some configuration before doing it becouse i tried everything and nothing works.

Codeigniter

```
public function catchData(){
        $CIarray = ...
        print_r($CIarray);

}
```

Angular

```
$scope.sendToControler = function () {
      $scope.prosek = {kalorije: 0.0, proteini: 0.0, uh: 0.0, masti: 0.0};
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's worked for me: On the angular side:

```
  return $http({method: "POST", 
               dataType: "json",
               url:'/myURL/', 
               data: $.param({data: JSON.stringify(data)}), 
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
        .success(function(data) {
          //Handle Success;
  });
```

On the PHP side

```
$CIarray = json_decode($_POST['data'])
```